# What is create new ad unit in Google Adsense?

Tags: google-adsense

I tried to send AdSense request to Google to display other ads in my website to earn money. In the AdSense Dashboard there is an option Create new ad unit to generate code?

What it is? Why do I have to insert that code in my website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display ads on your website Google needs to know:

- What size the ad should be
- Options such as what colors the ad should use
- Where on the page it should go
- How to track the ad and clicks on the ads

To make that happen you have to create an "ad unit" in the dashboard.  In the ad unit you specify the size and options.  Google then gives you a javascript snippet to put in your site that displays the ad in the place that you put that script.  The script contains the correct tracking information so that you get credit for clicks on the ad.